# How can I connect to Neo4J embedded instance using reactive driver?

Tags: java, neo4j, bolt

So far, I have been using this code to connect to embedded Neo4J instance:

```
DatabaseManagementService managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("neo")).build();
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = managementService.database(DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME);
```

(using [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j/4.0.0))

Now, I'm switching to [Neo4J driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.driver/neo4j-java-driver/4.0.0). But I don't know how to make the connection to embedded database. I tried this:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687");
```

but obviously is not working because there is no Neo4J server running, but just a database file. I guess I need to run bolt server first, exposing `neo` dir, that is where my database resides. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into the code, I found out that this code:

```
DatabaseManagementService managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("neo")).build();
```

actually starts a bolt server. So I did this:

```
DatabaseManagementService managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(new File("neo")).build();
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687");
```

and everything started working.